# VBA - Copy Sheets to new workbook without original workbook reference

Tags: excel, vba, reference, copy

I have a routine that is copying selected sheets from a "master" template workbook (containing all the templates for my customers) and pasting the selected sheets for a specific customer template into a new workbook (which the routine also generates).

The code works and importantly copies over formula's that pull text/data/values from a customer specific "DATA LOG SHEET" (which is always the first sheet amongst the selected sheets copied) across and into all the other selected sheets that are copied over into a new workbook.

However, it also copies over the reference to the original sheets in the "master", for example:

```
='[MasterTemplate.xlsm]DATA LOG SHEET (CUSTOMER NAME)'!B10)
```

The worksheets I'm copying need to be copied in the exact same formatting, here's routine I have currently:

```
Sub ArrayCustomerDocPackTemplateGenerator()

Dim myArray() As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim OldBook As String
Dim newBook As String
Dim a As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:B11")
'Or the range with your sheetnames

OldBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

For Each Cell In myRange
    If Not Cell = "" Then
        a = a + 1
        ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To a)
        myArray(a) = Cell
    End If
Next

For a = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    If a = 1 Then
        Sheets(myArray(a)).Copy
        newBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Workbooks(OldBook).Activate
    Else
        Sheets(myArray(a)).Copy After:=Workbooks(newBook).Sheets(a - 1)
        Workbooks(OldBook).Activate
    End If
Next

MsgBox "New Customer Doc Pack generated!", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

I've created multiple copies of this routine tied to buttons for each customer. The only real difference in each version of the routine is the range of cells (listing the specific customer sheet names) that the routine pulls from.

My question is, is there a way to copy a selection of sheets with all of their formatting and internal formulas to a new workbook every time without copying the cell workbook reference of the "Master" Template?

Also, does my routine need to generate and/or name a new workbook **first** and **then** copy the sheets from the "Master" template over to work?

If so, how do I do that?

Comment: *...without copying the cell workbook reference of the "Master" Template?* Nope. You are copying the formulas, so there is no way  in a single step. But you can copy the formulas and then update the references with replace or something like it.

Comment: So currently I'm manually doing that by opening up the new workbook that's created (after saving it) and going through Update Links, then Edit Links manually etc - can I get my routine to update the references and replace with "" **after** the sheets are copied in the new workbook?

Comment: Yes, check [Replace Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function). And if you need an example, use the macro recorder to replace `'[MasterTemplate.xlsm]DATA LOG SHEET (CUSTOMER NAME)'` by `DATA LOG SHEET (CUSTOMER NAME)` (I guess you are after that), and adapt the code to your needs.